# I cannot use webview.loadurl in android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, webview

Import like this

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
```

and then:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web1);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
```

But the it shows errors for line "myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");"

Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token ""http://google.com"", delete 
     this token
    - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

What's wrong with me?

Comment: Any logcat stack trace?

Comment: Also post your manifest file.

Comment: Please post a complete code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

your site will never load in your app, it will always ask to open with a external browser because you are missing some code. The following will work.

```
setContentView(R.layout.nameof_your_webview_xml_file_here);
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web1);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
```

you forgot to set your view as the web client. also if the page uses javascript i think you will need:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

put that line above the line where you setWebClient. This should work.. it is working for me. I use it to load my companies url, Facebook and twitter sites.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the following code:

```
           mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);   
           mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);         
           mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 

           // Load URL
           mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.firstdroid.com/advertisement.htm");
```

Also, make sure your manifest file has following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: else you can make use of [this](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/)

Comment: I use <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> already

Comment: check out the link which i posted above..If you follow it properly then you wont get any errors

Comment: yest but I have just learned so I dont understand much about the code

Answer (score 0):

Try by passing  URL/String variable.